# EFS is getting unmounted from lambda when there is an update to efs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I have created EFS, and mounted this on lambda using terraform. It works, but when there is an update in EFS, then EFS gets unmounted.

I need terraform to detect this update and automatically mount it in the  lambda like before.

Please help how can i solve this using terraform.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the details of your current terraform solution?